# ERROR: pq: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, upsert

I have this visitor table structure like below and I have created the upsert procedure to this table. When I call the procedure it returns `ERROR: pq: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification`. Can anyone please suggest the required changes.

```sql
CREATE TABLE visitors
(
    id               SERIAL    NOT NULL,

    facebook         TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    github           TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    linkedin         TEXT      NOT NULL,
    twitter          TEXT      DEFAULT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE visitors ADD CONSTRAINT visitors_primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id);

ALTER TABLE visitors ADD CONSTRAINT visitors_urls UNIQUE (facebook, github, linkedin, twitter);
```

The upsert procedure:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE visitors_upsert
(
    _facebook             TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    _github               TEXT      DEFAULT NULL,
    _linkedin             TEXT      DEFAULT '',
    _twitter              TEXT      DEFAULT NULL
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO visitors
    (
        facebook,
        github,
        linkedin
    )
    VALUES
    (
        _facebook,
        _github,
        _linkedin,
        _twitter
    )
    ON CONFLICT (linkedin)
    DO UPDATE 
    SET
        facebook = _facebook,
        github = _github,
        twitter = _twitter
$$;
```

```sql
CALL visitors_upsert('facebook', 'github', 'linkedin', 'twitter')
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=21ed4fa7526a0744feecbbe43f8944f6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no unique constraint on `linkedin`. Either create one, or use something else than `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: I have this unique constraint: `ALTER TABLE visitors ADD CONSTRAINT visitors_urls UNIQUE (facebook, github, linkedin, twitter);`, Is this not enough?

Comment: No. That makes *the combination* of those four values unique, but not each column.

Comment: I thought it does each column unique.